# Accessing OneDrive from Azure Mobile Service

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, live-sdk, onedrive

I'm developing a mobile app to share some content between users and I'm facing a weird problem.

Currently, what the app does is to allow the users to download some files from the web and store them on their *OneDrive* account.

The problem is that I need to download the file from the web first, and then upload it to *OneDrive*, and this means that I'm wasting double bandwidth for each file (*OneDrive* does not allow to upload a remote file).

The other required feature is to upload a file from *OneDrive* to my *Azure* storage, so, basically, I need my *Azure* service to work with both upload/download from/to *OneDrive*.

I can't find anything useful online, but I think I got a solution for the *OneDrive*-to-*Azure* scenario:

- Get the file ID using the *LiveSDK* on my phone
- Build a download link for the given file
- Send the link to the *Azure Mobile Service*
- Download the file in the *Azure Storage*

I've not tried it yet because I still got no access to *Azure* (I need to register for the trial), but I'm not sure that this may work, and even if it does I still need to figure out how to make the *Azure*-to-*OneDrive* stuff.

Do you guys have any clues?
This thing is really driving me insane :\

Comment: Well I haven't done it specifically with Azure and OneDrive but I have some something similar with Amazon S3 and Azure and yes it is the best approach. Build a url then pass it along for the other service to use rather than download then upload.

Comment: I did some tests but I can't seem to find a way to generate the download link from the `LiveSDK`, can you please share your code?

Comment: You can find information on retrieving a download URL here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659726.aspx#download_a_file

Essentially, the following call will redirect to the file for download:
GET https://apis.live.net/v5.0/[file ID]/content?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&download=1